# Alert on Pop Up Close

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a  Window Pop up, using below code:

UPDATED CODE:

**Parent.html**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PopUp();">Pop Up</a>

<script>
 var popup;
 function PopUp() {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display="block";

    popup = window.open('popup.html', 'Google', width=700, height=600);

     popup.onbeforeunload = function(){  
     alert("close");        
     document.getElementById('myModal').style.display="none";
   }
}
</script>
```

**POPUP.html**

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

My requirement is that whenever someone close the Window Pop up there should be alert on Parent.html. As we don't have any control on Pop up window.

Is, there any way to do this.??

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like thhis....

```
$.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Simple confirm!',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $.alert('Confirmed!');
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Canceled!');
        },
        somethingElse: {
            text: 'Something else',
            btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
            action: function(){
                $.alert('Something else?');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of `window.open`:

```
let popup = window.open()
popup.onbeforeunload = function(){ }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

*EDIT*

It only works if the popup opens the site in the same domain.

Comment: can you elaborate please.?? as i m new to this

Comment: Maybe you could try opening a document in in the same domain and in that document have redirect using javascript?

Comment: I have try your way, making an popup.html and using window.location to redirect it to three party, but the onbeforeunload function is called on the same time when pop is loaded not on closing the popup

Comment: If the site you want to open in a popup allows to be displayed in an iftame, you could try that.